# Как сделать фоновую картину header что бы занимал 70% экрана?

Tags: css

Как сделать фоновую картину header что бы занимал 70% экрана? И сразу ним main был без пропуска?

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}
* {
  margin: 0;

}

  
  border: solid;
   background-image: url(); 
  height: 70%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; 
  
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-container{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 85px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="img-container">
    
      <div class="inner-container">
             
          <nav><a href="1.html">Чебурашка</a> | <a href="2.html">Гена</a> |
            <a href="3.html">Шапокляк</a> | <a href="4.html">Лариска</a></nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </header>
  <main class="container">  
  <aside class="menu-primary">111 111 111 111</aside>
  <section class="main">
    <p>main</p>
    <p>main</p>
    <p>main</p>
    <p>main</p>
  </section>
    <aside class="menu-secondary">555 5551 5551 555</aside>

  </main>
  <footer class="footer">footer footer footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы какой-то элемент занимал 70% экрана, ему надо задавать высоту не в %, а в vh.

Comment: спасибо! Помогло!